# The use of definite article with phrases including "of"

Tags: british-english, definite-articles

Can we sometimes write the "of-phrases" without the definite article? I give few examples. Can we remove the definite articles marked boldly?

> However, **the** identification of relevant covariates needed in modelling can often be challenging.

> These allow transparent dealing with confounding bias by enabling **the** controlling of causal assumptions.

> The provided code allows **the** full production of our findings.

Comment: I haven't come across a rule that a definite article should precede phrases having 'of'. Of the three examples, 1) and 3) conveys the intended meanings without 'the', but the second example will sound odd without 'the'.

Comment: The element ***of relevant covariates*** is irrelevant to the syntax of the containing utterance. In all your examples including the word ***the*** is an optional stylistic choice. But to my mind, an "of- clause" is effectively doing the same thing as an ***adjective*** (modifying some adjacent noun phrase), so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples, **identification**; **controlling**, and **production** are, in their respective contexts, all uncountable nouns: they therefore do not **require** a determiner.

However, there is a tendency with uncountable nouns to use an optional determiner **when the uncountable noun is defined:**

**identification** is defined by *of relevant covariates*;

**controlling** is defined by *of causal assumptions*

and

**production** is defined by *of our findings*

Hence the *the*.

You will note that defining the noun makes it specific, thus licensing “the”.

Another “However”:

The “**of**” is not unique in its ability to define. All the “of” phrases above are adjuncts – *preposition + noun phrase/clause, gerund, pronoun, etc.* These act as modifiers. In your example they are adjectival modifiers.